# Pierde color de fondo elemento menú al realizar una operación CSS

Tags: css, menú, hover, li

Tengo un **panel de control del cliente** de una página web donde puede **gestionar todos sus datos.** Dispongo de **cuatro menús superiores**, según el cual elija se modifica el contenido del `cuerpo del body`.

El **problema** viene que a la hora de realizar cualquier operación: `añadir, modificar, eliminar,...` el hecho de pulsar sobre cualquier **botón**, bien pudiendo realizar la operación o no, **se desactiva el color del fondo del elemento menú** en el cual estábamos...

Al navegar entre las diferentes opciones del menú se mantiene todo correcto.

**¿A qué se debe?**

**Código CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#sesion_cliente{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    float: right;   
    text-align: right;
}

#menu_cliente{
    margin-top: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#menu_horizontal + #cuerpo_body{
    margin-top: 4em;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
}


.negrita{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
}

.deja_opinion{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}


#add_opinion input {
    margin: auto; 
    display: block;
}

#menu_horizontal {
    padding: 3px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #778;
    font: bold 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#menu_horizontal li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#menu_horizontal li a {
    padding: 3px 1em;
    border: 1px solid #778;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: #DDE;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu_horizontal li a:link {
    color: #448;
}

#menu_horizontal li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    border-color: #227;
}

/*
Usando el selector :target. 
Con :target se seleccionará el elemento con el id especificado en el identificador 
de fragmentos de la URI (la parte que va detrás del #).
*/
#menu_horizontal li:target a {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}


p.valoracion {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

p.valoracion input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}

p.valoracion label {
    float: right;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 30px;
}

p.valoracion label:hover,
p.valoracion label:hover ~ label,
p.valoracion input:checked ~ label {
    color: #FE0000;
}
```

**Código PHP/HTML:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Opiniones.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
        $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
    }else{
        header("Location: iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Añadir opinion"...
    if(isset($_POST["add_opinion"]) && isset($_POST['texto_opinion'])){
        $entrada = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['texto_opinion']);
        if(strlen($entrada) >  20 && strlen($entrada) < 300){
            $idemail = $cliente;
            $idcabana = $_POST["a_anadir"];
            $opinion = $_POST["texto_opinion"];
            $fecha = new DateTime();
            $fecha_hoy = $fecha->format ('Y/m/d');
            $valoracion = isset($_POST["estrellas"])?$_POST["estrellas"]: "0"; //Sin marcar estrellas, valoracion=0.
            BD::insertarOpinionPorReserva($idemail, $idcabana, $opinion, $fecha_hoy, $valoracion);
        }else{
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("¡Debes escribir una opinión entre 20-300 caracteres!");</script>';
        }
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar opinion"...
    if(isset($_POST["eliminar_opinion"])){
        $a_eliminar = $_POST["a_eliminar"];
        //Llamamos al método "borrarOpinion" y le pasamos el parámetro (idopinion).
        BD::borrarOpinion($a_eliminar);
    }


    $modificar_mensaje = false;
    //Si pulsamos el botón "Modificar"...
    if(isset($_POST["modificar"])){
        $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
        //Llamamos al método "modificarCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro (teléfono).
        BD::modificarCliente($cliente, $telefono);
        //Si debemos mostrar el mensaje, la estructura es la siguiente.
        $modificar_mensaje = ["¡OK!", "¡Teléfono modificado correctamente!", "success"];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Panel del cliente</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/seleccion_radio.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/seleccionar_elemento_li.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos_menu_cliente.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos_datos_personales.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_telefono.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>     
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_blanco.jpg">
        <div id="sesion_cliente">
            <?php 
            //Si NO existe la sesión "cliente", nos redirige a "error404.php"...
            if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                echo "<p class='negrita'>Bienvenido ".$cliente."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='reservar.php?salir=1'>Salir</a></p>";
                //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "cliente".
                    unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="menu_cliente">
            <ul class="menu_horizontal" id="menu_horizontal">
                <li class="nueva" id="nueva"><a class="active" href="menu_cliente.php?nueva=1#nueva">NUEVA OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li class="ver" id="ver"><a href="menu_cliente.php?ver=1#ver">VER OPINIONES</a></li>
                <li class="eliminar" id="eliminar"><a href="menu_cliente.php?eliminar=1#eliminar">ELIMINAR OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li class="datos_cliente" id="datos_cliente"><a href="menu_cliente.php?datos_cliente=1#datos_cliente">DATOS PERSONALES</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cuerpo_body">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el link "Nueva opinión"...
                if(isset($_GET["nueva"])){
                    //Llamamos al método "obtenerReservasPorCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro del email del cliente.
                    $reservas = BD::obtenerReservasPorCliente($cliente);
                    echo "<form action='menu_cliente.php?nueva=1' name='form_add_opinion' id='form_add_opinion' method='POST'>";
                    $selected = true;
                    foreach ($reservas as $reserva){
                        $idreserva = $reserva["idreserva"];
                        $idcabana = $reserva["idcabana"];
                        $idemail = $reserva["idemail"];
                        $check_in = new DateTime($reserva["check_in"]);
                        $check_out = new DateTime($reserva["check_out"]);
                        $reserva_toString = "Reserva de la cabaña ".$idcabana. " | ".$idemail. " | ".$check_in->format('d/m/Y'). " | ".$check_out->format('d/m/Y')."<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<input type='radio' name='a_anadir' value='".$reserva["idcabana"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"").">".$reserva_toString."</input>";
                        $selected = false;
                    }
                    echo "<br/><p class='deja_opinion'><img class='bajar_imagen' src='imagenes/escribir.png' height='18px' width='18px' alt='escribir'/> Deja tu opinión:</p><br/>";
                    echo "<textarea rows='4' cols='56' id='texto_opinion' name='texto_opinion' required></textarea><br/>";
                    echo "<p class='valoracion'>";
                        echo "<input id='radio1' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='5'>";
                        echo "<label for='radio1'>★</label>";
                        echo "<input id='radio2' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='4'>"; 
                        echo "<label for='radio2'>★</label>";
                        echo "<input id='radio3' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='3'>"; 
                        echo "<label for='radio3'>★</label>";
                        echo "<input id='radio4' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='2'>"; 
                        echo "<label for='radio4'>★</label>";
                        echo "<input id='radio5' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='1'>"; 
                        echo "<label for='radio5'>★</label>";
                    echo "</p><br/>";

                    echo "<input type='submit' name='add_opinion' id='add_opinion' value='Añadir opinión'>";
                    echo "</form>";
                }


                //Si pulsamos el link "Ver opiniones"...
                if(isset($_GET["ver"])){
                    //Llamamos al método "obtenerOpinionesPorCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro del email del cliente.
                    $opiniones = BD::obtenerOpinionesPorCliente($cliente);
                    if($opiniones != null){
                        foreach ($opiniones as $opinion){
                            $fecha = new DateTime($opinion["fecha"]);
                            $comentario = $fecha->format('d/m/Y')." (".$opinion["idemail"].") - ".$opinion["opinion"]."<br/><br/>";
                            echo $comentario;
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "<h1>¡No existen opiniones!</h1>";
                        echo "<img src='imagenes/advertencia.png' height='160px' width='220px' alt='Advertencia'>";
                    }
                }


                //Si pulsamos el link "Eliminar opinión"...
                if(isset($_GET["eliminar"])){
                    //Llamamos al método "obtenerOpinionesPorCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro del email del cliente.
                    $opiniones = BD::obtenerOpinionesPorCliente($cliente);
                    if($opiniones != null){
                        echo "<form action='menu_cliente.php?eliminar=1' name='form_a_eliminar' id='form_a_eliminar' method='POST'>";
                            $selected = true;
                            foreach ($opiniones as $opinion){
                                $fecha = new DateTime($opinion["fecha"]);
                                $comentario = $fecha->format('d/m/Y')."(".$opinion["idemail"].") - ".$opinion["opinion"]."<br/><br/>";
                                echo "<input type='radio' name='a_eliminar' value='".$opinion["idopinion"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"").">".$comentario."</input>";
                                $selected = false;
                            }
                            echo "<input type='submit' name='eliminar_opinion' id='eliminar_opinion' value='Eliminar opinión'>";
                        echo "</form>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<h1>¡No existen opiniones!</h1>";
                        echo "<img src='imagenes/advertencia.png' height='160px' width='220px' alt='Advertencia'>";
                    }
                }


                //Si pulsamos el link "Datos personales"...
                if(isset($_GET["datos_cliente"])){
                    //Obtengo todos los datos del cliente.
                    $objeto_cliente = BD::obtenerCliente($cliente); ?>
                <form action="menu_cliente.php?datos_cliente=1" name="miformulario" id="miformulario"  method="POST" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar_telefono();">
                    <h2 class="form-titulo">MODIFICAR DATOS</h2>
                    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="input-2" value="<?php echo $objeto_cliente->getNombre();?>"  disabled>
                        <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" class="input-2" value="<?php echo $objeto_cliente->getApellidos();?>"  disabled>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="text" name="idemail" id="email" class="input-1" value="<?php echo $objeto_cliente->getIdemail();?>"  disabled>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" maxlength="9" class="input-2" value="<?php echo $objeto_cliente->getDni();?>"  disabled>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" maxlength="9" class="input-2" value="<?php echo $objeto_cliente->getTelefono();?>" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
                        <br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Modificar" name="modificar" class="registrar"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <?php 
                }
                //Si hemos definido un contenido $mostrar, es hora de utilizarlo.
                if ($modificar_mensaje !== false) {
                ?>
                    <script>
                    //De esta manera se generará el código Javascript necesario para mostrar la alerta sólo 
                    //si ésta se requiere. He usado "json_encode" para convertir datos PHP en datos Javascript de manera segura.
                        swal(
                            <?= json_encode($modificar_mensaje[0]) ?>,
                            <?= json_encode($modificar_mensaje[1]) ?>,
                            <?= json_encode($modificar_mensaje[2]) ?>
                        );
                    </script>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Debería agregar solo el `HTML` y `CSS` del elemento en cuestión y dejarlo ejecutable. En el `css` no veo nada que lo pueda cambiar, usa alguna libreria? o en  `JS` revise si el `id` de su elemento choca con el de algún otro

Comment: El problema es que no es cuestión de las librerías ni de los ids, debido a que si navego entre los elementos <ul li> del menú funciona correctamente, el problema viene a la hora de pulsar un botón que se desactiva el color de los elementos <ul li>

Comment: agregue algunas capturas entonces

Comment: Si puedes agregar un link, mejor, ya que con PHP no se puede emular el error.

Comment: Tampoco es necesario, pegar todo el código php o html, sino solo donde esta presentando el error, es bastante complejo estudiar código ajeno, más aún ejecutarlo mentalmente y se complica más cuando son biblias de código jejeje. En buen plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mantener el color al recibir el foco utilizar la **pseudo-class :focus**  de CSS:

```
#menu_horizontal li a:focus {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Sin embargo al presionar en otro lugar lo perdera.

Podrias mantener el color del boton seleccionado de esta forma:

```js
$(function() {
          $("#menu_cliente ul li a").click(function() {
            $("#menu_cliente ul li a").removeClass("seleccionado");
            $(this).addClass("seleccionado");
          });
        });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#sesion_cliente{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    float: right;   
    text-align: right;
}

#menu_cliente{
    margin-top: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#menu_horizontal + #cuerpo_body{
    margin-top: 4em;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
}


.negrita{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
}

.deja_opinion{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}


#add_opinion input {
    margin: auto; 
    display: block;
}

#menu_horizontal {
    padding: 3px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #778;
    font: bold 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#menu_horizontal li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#menu_horizontal li a {
    padding: 3px 1em;
    border: 1px solid #778;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: #DDE;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu_horizontal li a:link {
    color: #448;
}

#menu_horizontal li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    border-color: #227;
}

/*
Usando el selector :target. 
Con :target se seleccionará el elemento con el id especificado en el identificador 
de fragmentos de la URI (la parte que va detrás del #).
*/
/*#menu_horizontal li a:focus {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}*/

/*
Codigo Agregado
 */
#menu_horizontal li a.seleccionado {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}



p.valoracion {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

p.valoracion input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}

p.valoracion label {
    float: right;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 30px;
}

p.valoracion label:hover,
p.valoracion label:hover ~ label,
p.valoracion input:checked ~ label {
    color: #FE0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu_cliente">
            <ul class="menu_horizontal" id="menu_horizontal">
                <li class="nueva" id="nueva"><a class="active" href="#">NUEVA OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li class="ver" id="ver"><a href="#">VER OPINIONES</a></li>
                <li class="eliminar" id="eliminar"><a href="#">ELIMINAR OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li class="datos_cliente" id="datos_cliente"><a href="#">DATOS PERSONALES</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas, saludos.